# WebGL with Viewer - Can't use multiple render targets. Falling back to two passes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How it is reproduced:
I go to the page where the viewer is used. Let's say, while waiting for it to fully load (it doesn't matter), there is no error in the console. Next, I go to another page on the site where the viewer is used.

When I load the page, an error appears in the console(attach a screenshot). After that, if I try to draw the model in the viewer, the viewer does not draw the model completely. And the viewer does not allow you to work with elements (for example, selection).

As a result of what could this error appear?
I didn't do anything special with the initialization of the viewer

Viewer verssion - 7.65

[image: chrome devtools console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to run the viewer in multiple browsers/tabs at the same time. Each tab should be using its own GPU context. I just tried loading the following URLs in different browsers at the same time, and all the viewers are rendering the models correctly:

- https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com/#dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtYmFzaWMtYXBwLWJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0
- https://forge-basic-app.herokuapp.com/#dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtYmFzaWMtYXBwLWJ1Y2tldC9TcG9ydHMlMjBDYXIuZHdmeA

Are you seeing this issue with *any* Forge app (like the one I linked to), or just with your own one? And have you tried other browsers and other devices? It could also be hardware-related. Perhaps your hardware has fewer resources, and when one of the browser tabs loses context, the viewer cannot recover from that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I observe the problem only with my own Forge application. We are probably shutting down the viewer incorrectly.